# Right sentence for keep a date in mind

Tags: sentence

A friend will get married and she made a banner with "Save the date" expression, expecting her friends to memorize/annotate the marriage date. The sentence doesn't feels right to me, but I could not think in any other option. What sentence could be more appropriated for this case?

Comment: _save the date_ is a common expression in many parts of the world. Could you better explain what doesn't feel right? If it helps, it's an imperative clause, meaning it doesn't need a subject, hence why it's so brief.

Comment: it doesn't sound 100% ok to me at first, just it. I am still learning english tho.

Comment: It doesn't sound OK to me either (and I'm English). It sounds like 'Save the Whale' or 'Save the Panda'. 'Save this date' seems a lot better but as the answers below appear to suggest it's common in English speaking countries outside of the UK, it won't belong until it gets to the UK - it may already be there.

Comment: *Save the Date* (I) (2012)  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1965065/ http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ0OTExOTUyNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjkwOTI2OA@@._V1_SY317_CR2,0,214,317_AL_.jpg

Comment: Frank, that's a good point. It sounds weird to me and, is not common in the UK. It's probably a part of American English in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending out "Save the Date" invitations or announcements is a common thing to do before a wedding, at least in America. Your friend was correct.

Do a google search of "save the date origin" for much more information.

Answer (score 1):

"Save the date" is well-understood and expected language to appear on an advance missive sent up-to 6 months prior to the wedding invitation.  Any other language on such advance notices runs the risk of being misunderstood in purpose or intent.

That said, I have never seen "Save the Date" *on a banner.*  In that context, it makes very little sense.  The expectation that anyone seeing the banner would get out their planners or smart phones and take note of the date on the spot is discourteous in the extreme.

At a gathering to announce a betrothal ***"We're Engaged!"*** would be more celebratory.  (No wedding date would accompany that announcement on the banner.)  A follow-up "Save the Date" via mail or email would be more customary.  If the bride insists on communicating the wedding date on the spot, I would encourage her to print small cards and leave them on a table for guests to take-away *if they are so inclined* to make note at their convenience.

Answer (score 1):

The "save the date" card is an optional American (at least) wedding tradition. It acts as a "pre-invitation."

The couple getting married would send "save-the-date" cards as soon as the wedding date is decided on. It is meant to tell people that they will be receiving a formal wedding invitation at a later date, so they shouldn't schedule anything else for that weekend.

The invitations will be sent out closer to the actual day, once details like catering choices, reception venue, etc. have been decided on.

I think your confusion arises from seeing "save" here as though you were "saving" something on a computer--to record the date in some permanent form. "Save" here means to "save" the day itself; to refrain from making other plans for that day. Just like you would say,

> Save the last piece of pie for me,

you are saying,

> Save June 14th for my wedding.

In this context, a banner (I'm not sure what banner you mean) makes sense; she is telling her friends to prepare for her wedding by clearing their calendars.

Answer (score 1):

Encyclopedia Free Dictionary has this entry sourced from an earlier Wikipedia entry:

[**Save the date**](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/save+the+date)

> A **save the date** is a notice stating the date of a significant event such as a wedding. It is typically sent to those likely to be interested or affected by the event and states the planned date of the occasion so that recipients who wish to attend know to keep that date free.
>   
>   For weddings, save the dates usually take the form of a card. They are generally sent out at least six to twelve months before the wedding date, and are usually followed by a formal wedding invitation. While save the date started as a wedding-related custom, it is now used by individuals, businesses, and organizations to announce the date of any formal event.

It seems the WP entry no longer exists, though.